# initialize values of a nested struct from a file

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, struct, format-specifiers

I'm having trouble with struct in C, could anyone help? I'm new to C and structure so please be kind to me. I have declared two structs below and one of them is nested inside another.

```
struct orders_tag {
    int number_of_orders;
    char item_name[20];
    int price;
};

typedef struct orders_tag order;

struct customer_tag {
    char name[30];
    order total_order[10];
};

typedef struct customer_tag customer;
```

I have initialized these values in main as well.

```
customer cus_array[20];
customer c;
```

I'm trying to read the information from the file and put those values into my nested structs but I really don't understand what is going on here.  Any explanations would be appreciated.

```
infile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

if (infile == NULL) {
    printf("Couldn't open the fire.");
    return 1;
}

while (fscanf(infile, "%s %d %s %2f", c.name, c.total_order.number_of_orders
        , c.total_order.item_name, c.total_order.price) != EOF) {

}
```

I believe the only errors I got is from the while loop condition.

Comment: `total_order` is an array. So this `c.total_order.item_name` and this `c.total_order.price` will not compile.

Comment: thanks, I'll think i'll make some local temp variables and put the values from file into those temp variables and then manually initialize the struct from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `price` is defined as `int` and you're using `%2f` to read the value. Not correct.

Just for reference, chapter 7.19.6.2, paragraph 10, `C99` standard,

> Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>   the format argument that has not already received a conversion result.If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

Next, with `fscanf()`, you're supposed to supply the pointers of the memory locations where the value has to be stored. You need to use `&` as required.

Also, in `c.total_order.number_of_orders` case(s), `total_order` is an array, so you've to use the array subscript to denote to a particular variable in the array. something like

```
c.total_order[i].number_of_orders
```

where `i` is used as index.

Comment: Look at totalorder it is an array. There is problem with it also

Comment: @Gopi Thanks sir. Also addressed the issue in `fscanf()`  :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot of good answers here but since you answered first I'll pick your answer.

Comment: @ln206 Glad it helped. For all good answers, you always have a choice to upvote to show the future visitors of this question that those answers are good and useful. Cheers !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Within the customer_tag struct you declared total_order as an array, you should reference each element when scanning in the values. Also, a & is needed before the int values in the fscanf

```
while (fscanf(infile, "%s %d %s %2f", c.name, &(c.total_order[0].number_of_orders)
        , c.total_order[0].item_name, &(c.total_order[0].price)) != EOF) {}
```

just maybe have some sort of incrementer to change which element of the total_order array you are accessing

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
while (fscanf(infile, "%s %d %s %d", &c.name,&c.total_order[i].number_of_orders
        , &c.total_order[i].item_name, &c.total_order[i].price) == 4) {
i++;
}
```

Just adding the code on how to read values to your structure.